# using an array and array lists

Tags: java, arrays

My project is to create a program that does this:

> The array of type double called grades has been initialized with the
>   test scores for a class. The course instructor would like the highest
>   score, the lowest score, and the mean value of all the grades.

I'm getting the following errors when I compile the following code:

```
File: C:\Users\Guest\Downloads\grades.java [line: 16]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
File: C:\Users\Guest\Downloads\grades.java [line: 23]
Error: grades cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\Guest\Downloads\grades.java [line: 23]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
```

```java
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class grades
{
 // global variable declaration
 static Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
 static final double NUM_GRADES = 5;

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      // declare variables
      double highestGrade = -999999;
      double lowestGrade = 999999;
      double sumOfGrades = 0;
      double avgGrades = 0;
      double[] scores = new double[NUM_GRADES]; // array is initialized using a final variable

      // use a for loop to obtain data from  user using the final variable
      for(double index=0; index < NUM_GRADES; ++index)
      {

          // this puts data into the current array index
           grades[index] = cin.nextDouble();

           // this calculates a running total of all the scores
           sumOfGrades += grades[index];

           // if current score in the array index is bigger than the current 'highestScore'
           // value, then set 'highestScore' equal to the current value in the array
           if(grades[index] > highestGrade)
           {
                highestGrade = grade[index];
           }

           // if current score in the array index is smaller than the current 'lowestScore'
           // value, then set 'lowestScore' equal to the current value in the array
           if(lowestGrade > grades[index])
           {
                lowestGrade = grades[index];
           }               
      }

      {
           System.out.print("\nThe grade for student #"+(index+1)+" is: "+grades[index]);
      }

      // display the highest/lowest numbers to the screen
      System.out.print("\n\nThese are the highest and lowest grades: ");
      System.out.print("\n\tHighest: "+ highestGrade);
      System.out.print("\n\tLowest: "+ lowestGrade);

 // find the average
 avgScores = sumOfGrades/NUM_GRADES;
 System.out.print("\nThe average score is: "+ avgGrades);

 // reset data back to 0 so we can find the ommitted average
 sumOfGrades = 0;
 avgGrades = 0;

}
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about those errors? They seem self-explanatory.

Comment: Use 0.0 or 999.0 instead and see? Apart from that, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Doubles are floating point numbers.  `NUM_GRADES` is a double.  it could have a value like 3.2 or 42.01.  What would an array with that many elements look like?  The size of an array (and thus, `NUM_GRADES`) needs to be an integer.

Comment: You also have the class name and variable named declared the same. What is  grades[index] supposed to be if grades is the name of the class?

Comment: "grades" is your class name but you're using it as if it's an array.  Perhaps you meant "scores"

Comment: @TejaswiRana Java has rules in place for figuring that out.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Perhaps the errors are self-explanatory to you, but to someone just beginning to learn programming they may not be. Please try to be more understanding and less smug.

Comment: @JasonPather Don't give me that. There aren't 1000 ways to interpret `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int` or `grades cannot be resolved to a variable`. On top of that, there are tons of questions on this site and elsewhere on the web that explain where those errors come from. The OP hasn't shown any effort.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use an `int` as the size in between brackets `[]` for an array size.  Declare your `NUM_GRADES` constant to be an `int`, not a `double`.

You declared an double array called `scores`, but you don't use it, and then you refer to `grades` which doesn't exist.  Either change all `grades` references to `scores` or change the name of `scores` to `grades`.

Answer (score 3):

- `Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int` - you are initializing an array using double as the size, which is not allowed, change NUM_GRADES type to int:

  ```
  static final int NUM_GRADES = 5;
  ```
- `Error: grades cannot be resolved to a variable` - you don't have a variable called grades, that's why the compiler is complaining; probably your variable `scores` should be called `grades`
- `Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int` - you are using double to index an array in `for loop`, change it to int:

  ```
  for (int index = 0; index < NUM_GRADES; ++index)
  ```

**EDIT (few more):**

- variable `grade` doesn't exist in this piece of code:

  ```
  if(grades[index] > highestGrade)
  {
      highestGrade = grade[index]; //<------- change it to grades
  }
  ```
- your print() statement is outside `for loop`, so index variable will not be accessible; move it inside the loop
- `avgScores` is also not declared as variable, it should probably be avgGrades, which you declared at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

For the "cannot convert from double to int" error, you can force a conversion by casting to int e.g. `grades[index] = (int)cin.nextDouble();` but this amounts to "chopping off" the decimal places from the double and you end up with an int that is basically "rounded down" if that makes sense.

For the "grades cannot be resolved to a variable" error "grades" has not been declared as a variable whatsoever (like scores was).

Comment: Note, I am not telling you that you should cast the double, but that you can. I think a more appropriate solution is to use the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

NUM_GRADE is a double. You can't use doubles as an index to an array. Try declaring it as an int instead, like this:

`static final int NUM_GRADES = 5;`

You made the same mistake with `index`. Declare it as an int.

`grades` doesn't exist. You probably meant to use `scores`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix compile time errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grade //changed here
{
 // global variable declaration
 static Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
 static final int NUM_GRADES = 5;//changed here

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  // declare variables
  double highestGrade = -999999;
  double lowestGrade = 999999;
  double sumOfGrades = 0;
  double avgGrades = 0;
  double[] scores = new double[NUM_GRADES]; // array is initialized using a final variable

  // use a for loop to obtain data from  user using the final variable
  for(int index=0; index < NUM_GRADES; ++index)//changed here
  {

      // this puts data into the current array index
       //changed here
       scores[index] = cin.nextDouble();

       // this calculates a running total of all the scores
       sumOfGrades += scores[index];//changed here

       // if current score in the array index is bigger than the current 'highestScore'
       // value, then set 'highestScore' equal to the current value in the array
       if(scores[index] > highestGrade) //changed here
       {
            highestGrade = scores[index]; //changed here
       }

       // if current score in the array index is smaller than the current 'lowestScore'
       // value, then set 'lowestScore' equal to the current value in the array
       if(lowestGrade > scores[index])
       {
            lowestGrade = scores[index];//changed here
       }               
  }

  {
       System.out.print("\nThe grade for student #"+(index+1)+" is: "+scores[index]);//changed here
  }

  // display the highest/lowest numbers to the screen
  System.out.print("\n\nThese are the highest and lowest grades: ");
  System.out.print("\n\tHighest: "+ highestGrade);
  System.out.print("\n\tLowest: "+ lowestGrade);

 // find the average
 avgScores = sumOfGrades/NUM_GRADES;
 System.out.print("\nThe average score is: "+ avgGrades);

 // reset data back to 0 so we can find the ommitted average
 sumOfGrades = 0;
 avgGrades = 0;

}
}
```

Comment: This will still not compile, as NUM_GRADES is of type double, and is used as an array size :) by the way, it would be useful if your comments of what has been changed were more visible

Comment: This still won't compile, because in `for loop`, index is of type double and is used to access array indexes :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(lowestGrade > grades[index])
```

...

```
System.out.print("\nThe grade for student #"+(index+1)+" is: "+grades[index]);
```

'index' would need to be an int (or cast to it) to be an array index.

This should fix you...

```
for(int index=0; index < NUM_GRADES; ++index)
```